# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement DoubleTable (from versions: none)

Tags: python

root@kali:~/xerosploit# pip3 install DoubleTable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement DoubleTable (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for DoubleTable

Comment: welcome  to SO.. when provided with an answer you should follow this link.... https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You do not install DoubleTable in that way...
You install terminaltables, this is the package you need [terminaltables 3.1.0](https://pypi.org/project/terminaltables/)

As per the DoubleTable documentation [doubletable](https://robpol86.github.io/terminaltables/doubletable.html#), check the [installation section](https://robpol86.github.io/terminaltables/install.html)

Answer (score 0):

after installing xerosploit you just download gedit
and install terminaltables and tabulate using pip3

sudo apt install gedit
pip3 install terminaltables
pip3 install tabulate

after that go to xerosploit folder and edit xerosploit.py
by writing the following command as:

gedit xerosploit.py

and replace all the raw_input to input

and then save and then run the file as:

python3 xerosploit.py

and then it will work

Comment: Hi mohammed and welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please format your code correctly? If you don't know how, here a [guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) for you